# PHP - Extract node value from nested xml file

Tags: php, xml

I have I'm trying to get the "extract" node value from an xml file/url. Below is my code, but I'm not getting any output.

```
<?php
$url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=xml&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=unix";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

echo $xml->extract ;
?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$xml->extract` would work if the node was a direct child of the xml file.

After looking at the api response, I am able to get and display the `extract` node using the full path:

```
$url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=xml&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=unix";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
echo $xml->query->pages->page->extract ;
```